# Process Builder calling Apex: "We can't find an action with the name and action type that you specified."

Tags: process-builder, action

I read the other references to this error, but I don't see one specifically relating to an Apex function call.  I deployed a Change Set with the Process, Custom Setting & Apex classes.  The class has an @invocable method, and the process, as constructed in the sandbox, works fine.

The action itself did not come over in the Change Set, and when I try to rebuild it I see the class & method listed, as well as the parameter I'm setting in the process.  I cannot save the action, however, because I am getting the "We can't find an action with the name and action type that you specified." error.

I'm going to try building a new Process that references the same method; will let you know how that goes.
...
Nope - same result.  Class/method/var(param) appears in flow, but Save() fails.

Comment: i've had similar issue with schedulable apex classes; I had to run tests on the apex class in PROD before SFDC acknowledged it was a valid class usable by apex scheduler; this may or may not be your issue but worth a shot

Comment: Nice one, @cropredy!  Worked a charm!

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I would do...

1. Locate the Apex Class in the offending org
2. Go to **Develop | Apex Classes |** *the class*
3. See if the `Status` says it is active. If not, step 4
4. Use Developer Console or **Setup | Develop | Apex Test Execution** and run the tests for that class.

This should make the class active and available for use in Process Builder

*(adapted from a similar experience with schedulable classes not available for the Apex Scheduler)*