# Missing Apex Action (legacy) in environment - unable to refer the same on flow

Tags: visual-workflow, action

I have a class implementing Process.plugin interface and being used on an existing flow. Whenever I try to make any changes on the flow and save I get the *We can't find the Apex callout for class . It may have been deleted or changed.*

The same does work on higher environments . I'm not able to understand what am I missing here?

I tried resaving the class but it didn't work. Also, I thought of removing the action and again adding the same but when I add Apex Action on the flow and select Legacy as type I don't see the apex action on the list although there does exist a class ( can see this on higher orgs ).

Answer (score 1):

Bumped into [Process Builder calling Apex: "We can't find an action with the name and action type that you specified."](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120552/process-builder-calling-apex-we-cant-find-an-action-with-the-name-and-action?rq=1) post and the solution mentioned as to run the test class for the respective apex class solved the problem!